# How can I convert AdobeXD exact prototype to flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, adobe-xd

I was asked to convert the AdobeXD user interface design to an app. I decided to use flutter however when I converted it to flutter and debug all the errors, I finally managed to launch it in the emulator however the output is not the same as the design in adobe xd.

I did try to add dependencies in the **pubspec.yaml** for the `assets/image` however I still can't load the `assets/images` in my emulator.

| left: AdobeXD design right: android emulator display |
| --- |
| [image] |

Comment: follow this : https://sunitshirke.medium.com/convert-adobe-xd-prototypes-to-flutter-widgets-early-access-67cecd40c509

Comment: thank you for the suggestion